# How to add a leading zero when the length of the column is unknown?

Tags: postgresql, null, concatenation

How can I add a leading zero to a `varchar` column in the table and I don't know the length of the column. If the column is not null, then I should add a leading zero.

#### Examples:

345   - output should be 0345
4567  - output should be 04567

I tried:

```
SELECT lpad(column1,WHAT TO SPECIFY HERE?, '0') 
from table_name;
```

I will run an update query after I get this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be overthinking this. Use plain concatenation:

```
SELECT '0' || column1 AS padded_col1 FROM table_name;
```

If the column is NULL, nothing happens: concatenating anything to NULL returns NULL.

In particular, don't use [`concat()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER). You would get *'0'* for NULL columns, which you do *not* want.

If you also have empty strings (`''`), you may need to do more, depending on what you want.

And since you mentioned your plan to updated the table: Consider *not* doing  this, you are adding noise, that could be added for display with the simple expression. A [`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html) might come in handy for this.

If all your `varchar` values are in fact valid numbers, use an appropriate [numeric data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) instead and format for display with the same expression as above. The concatenation automatically produces a *text* result.

If circumstances should force your hand and you need to update anyway, consider this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET    column1 = '0' || column1
WHERE  column1 IS DISTINCT FROM '0' || column1;
```

The added `WHERE` clause to avoid empty updates. Compare:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input. Haven't run the update yet. Will get back if I run into any issues.

Answer (score 0):

try `concat` instead?..

```
SELECT concat(0::text,column1) from table_name;
```

Comment: This adds a zero if the column is null.

Comment: ah - I did not think about nulls